# What does this green symbol mean?

Tags: battlefield-hardline

What does this green symbol mean?  I am assuming it is the amount of players also currently using this item?   If so, in this case, does this mean 4 players are currently using the same gun AND accessory or just having no accessory 1st slot in their main weapon?

[image]

Comment: I'm pretty sure those symbols reflect the gear used by people in **your squad** only.

Answer (score 1):

It indicates the number of members in your squad using the selected accessory - in your case, no accessory.